# How to connect CakePHP application to Drupal Site?

Tags: drupal, cakephp

How to connect CakePHP application to Drupal Site Database, AND via RSS generated from Drupal site?

Edit:
let's say just connect via RSS generated from a Drupal site

Comment: database: `config/database.php`, rss: ?

Comment: @AmirAmgad use configuration of database in `/app/config/database.php`

Comment: Thanks Marek, but I did't mean configuration, I meant not combining CakePHP's database to Drupal's, but using both CakePHP's Database and Drupal's Database

Answer (score 0):

mmmm  unfortunately there is no  project in drupal that integrate Drupal with cakephp

but.. if you are Drupal developer and you want to [WORK WITH MULTIPLE DATABASES](http://drupal.org/node/18429) even if it wasn't drupal database... you can do this easly

Drupal has a [BUILT IN MODULE](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/aggregator) that support RSS

@see [RSS PROJECTS](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/rss?filters=ss_meta_type%3amodule)